# Sitecore Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

This seems like a really simple task to accomplish, but I can't seem to figure it out.  How do you assign validation to a particular field in Sitecore?

I can see the validation rules listed in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/`.

How do I assign a rule from here to a field on a template?

I've seen several blog posts about creating a custom OnSave action that evaluations the item and it's fields - that you then hook up in the web config - but that is way overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish.  None of the blog posts or pdfs from Sitecore itself seem to show how to set up really simple validation (or I can't find them).

Comment: For those that view this later, I ended up using regexs to validate the fields.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For some basic validation you can browse to your template, select the field itself (the field item underneath the template, I mean) and browse to the Validation Rules section.

Answer (score 12):

There is also another simple way (did not check if it stil exists in Sitecore 7).
Go to the template field itself, as Trayek says, and therer you have 2 fields: "Validation" and "ValidationText".
In Validation you enter the regex for the validation and in ValidationText you enter the text to display.

[image]

Comment: This still exists as of Sitecore 8.1. Also, you need to enter both Validation _and_ ValidationText for it to apply.

Answer (score 2):

Just set validation rule Item id in **Suppressed Validation Rules** field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First check the "Standard Fields" checkbox from "view" tab of top ribbon and go on data template of selected item, select field for validation, on this field you can find Validation Rules bar here you can apply validation.

Answer (score 1):

I would not just dump a regex in the validation field.  Creating a rule and assigning it on a template affords you a lot more flexability